File Manager not Launching in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 with the Dark Style used for the system and applications. The problem that begin appearing every single time Ubuntu is booting up is that it takes no less than 30 seconds for Files (Nautilus) to launch. And, after it launched, it uses the Light Style. Moreover, some other applications do not work also. Currently, repeated restarting Ubuntu until Nautilus launches right after boot up somehow solves the issue (and everything is in the Dark Style).
I've installed preload but it didn't help.
Is there any working solution?

Does closing with nautilus -q and opening with GSK_RENDERER=cairo nautilus changes anything? Do you see any errors or warning relating to graphics when launching in the terminal?

When the issue happens, the terminal doesn't start either. When there is no issue, I tried your commands and no error messages were shown. Only, when starting Nautilus from the terminal, closing it with the Close button doesn't end the process (it remains in the terminal and System Monitor.
